# DELPHI XE7 [dcc32 Error] E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Pos' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, dcc32

DELPHI XE7 on win7 32bit
code:

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
if (pos('CONNECT',AContext)<>0) or (pos('GET',AContext)<>0) or (pos('POST',AContext)<>0) or   (pos('HEAD',AContext)<>0)
then
(....)
sleep(100);
end;
```

error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(49): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Pos' that can be called with these arguments
```

please help me how to fix that code

thanks in advance

Comment: `TIdContext` probably isn't a string...

Comment: You might wanted to operate with `TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData` (which is not string). But without knowing you aim it's just a guess.

Comment: Obvious first steps when presented with an error message like that: (1) Identify which overloaded versions of the function exist. (2) Identify the arguments being used. Did you do those things?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand can you tell me wich one that code made error?

@TLama yes i'll use something like that on my previous indy scripts is like this

`if (pos('CONNECT',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('GET',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('POST',athread.NetData)<>0) or (pos('HEAD',athread.NetData)<>0)`

that working fine
but i wanna change to indy 10 but got that error 

@RobKennedy m new in delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to `Pos` are two strings. The functions searches for the first occurrence of a substring (the first parameter) within another string (the second parameter). The function is documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos

You are passing `AContext` which is of type `TIdContext` and that is not a string. To fix the code you need to pass the string that contains the text within which you intend to search.

Comment: can you give me an example how to use _pos_ if i wanna check is http header send **CONNECT** or **POST** or **GET** command?

Comment: Your code is fine so long as you can get the http header as a string. Can you do that?